# 1B pseudo-random boolean permutations of vector set N by M

Tags: python, performance, optimization, random, mathematical-optimization

Let's say we have a set of pseudo-random boolean/binary vectors of length N, and each vector is length M.

e.g. {[0,1,0,1], [0,0,0,1]}

We need one billion unique vectors.

**Now, the question is, what is the fastest way to do this?**? *(also please keep in mind we need to keep the vector set in memory, so that later we can use the same set to do other stuff)*

For example... here are some approaches I have tried...

```
## where N = 10 and M = 10,000
def idx_v(idx, ivals=vector_set(N,M), ival=np.zeros(10_000)):
  divs = idx // 10
  remains = idx % 10
  a = [divs,remains]
  hv = str( abs( hash( str(a) ) ) )
  ival = ivals[remains]
  for i in hv:
    ival = np.roll(ival, int(i))
  return ival, divs, remains

for idx in range(1_000_000_000):
  ival = idx_v(idx)
```

that takes about 0.006 seconds per generation of 10 vectors

```
##where N = 100 and M = 10,000 
def idx_v(idx, ivals=vector_set(N,M), ival=np.zeros(10_000)):
  divs = idx // 100
  remains = idx % 100
  ival = np.roll(ivals[remains], divs )
  return ival, divs, remains

for idx in range(1_000_000_000):
  ival = idx_v(idx)
```

that takes about 0.005 seconds per generation of 10 vectors

Comment: What is `vector_set`?

Comment: You OBVIOUSLY cannot hold the entire set in memory.  A billion vectors of integers of length 10,000 requires 40 terabytes.  You can recreate the set by setting the random seed before you start, but you can't hold them in memory.

Comment: @MichaelButscher vector_set generates the vector set of N by M. e.g. {[0,1,0,1], [0,0,0,1]} would be the vector set where N = 2 and M = 4.

One way to create the vector set is by the following:
np.random.randint(2, size=(N,M))

Comment: @TimRoberts The vector set is what we need to keep in memory, not the unique 1B vectors generated from this set. For example, see my comment to MichaelButscher.

Comment: If your initial vector set contains one item that is the `roll`ed variant of another, the resulting vectors may not be completely unique.

Comment: Plus, your code is only going to create 1,000,000 different arrangements.  Rolling a vector of 10,000 by 10,,002 is the same as rolling by 2.

Comment: Is your overall goal here to generate a repeatable series of a billion binary vectors of length 10,000?  Because THAT'S certainly doable.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes, my goal is to create a repeatable series of a **unique** billion binary vectors of length 10k as fast as possible...

Comment: Since you already pointed out that you're OK with a set of *pseudo*random vectors, you can simply either iterate through vectors generated from a fixed seed using the builtin pseudorandom number generator, or you can even use the index to each vector as the random seed for that vector, allowing you to arbitrarily index the vectors without holding all of them in memory.

Comment: @Grismar, that is the answer i believe b/c the seed(idx) vector is reproducible when we need that vector again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the complex mixing and operating on the numbers doesn't really do all that much. Here's a solution that allows you to either have a decent indexable collection of pseudorandom vectors, or allows you to reproduce the exact same indexable collection every time:

```
import numpy as np


def seeded_vector(n, i, seed=np.random.randint(0, np.iinfo(np.int32).max)):
    np.random.seed(seed + i)
    return np.random.randint(2, size=n)


print('10 random vectors of length 10:')
for i in range(10):
    print(seeded_vector(10, i))

print('and the same 10 vectors again:')
for i in range(10):
    print(seeded_vector(10, i))

print('a collection of 10 vectors that is fixed if the seed is set:')
for i in range(10):
    print(seeded_vector(10, i, seed=42))

print('and again:')
for i in range(10):
    print(seeded_vector(10, i, seed=42))
```

Output on my system:

```
10 random vectors of length 10:
[1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1]
[1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0]
[0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0]
[0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1]
[0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0]
[1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0]
[0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0]
and the same 10 vectors again:
[1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1]
[1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0]
[0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0]
[0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1]
[0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0]
[1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0]
[0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0]
a collection of 10 vectors that is fixed if the seed is set:
[0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]
[0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1]
[0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1]
[1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0]
[1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0]
[1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0]
[0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0]
[0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0]
and again:
[0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]
[0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1]
[0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1]
[1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0]
[1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0]
[1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0]
[0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0]
[0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0]
```

Note that the bottom two blocks will always be the exact same for every run, while the top two blocks will be random between runs, but always identical for each run.

Note that, depending on the exact algorithm used by Python/Numpy, it's possible you'd get the same result every time on one system, but not across all systems. I'd expect the result to be the same for any run on any machine - at least running a similar version of Python and Numpy. But I haven't investigated if that is guaranteed.

You were asking for the *fastest* solution - I doubt you can get a lot faster than this in terms of time up front, since it literally only takes the time to define the function that returns the vectors. However, if you have to access these vectors very frequently, you could consider adding some form of caching to the function so that the vectors don't have to be generated every time but can simply be looked up on repeat access.

However, I doubt the added overhead will be worth it, unless you access these very frequently indeed - and as others have pointed out, you may find you don't have enough memory to do that for the size of the collection you seem to need. Trading a tiny bit of speed for not needing any storage at all seems like a pretty good deal here.

If you always access the collection in order, or in fixed blocks, an optimisation could be to return these blocks in one go (or yield them from a generator), without setting the seed before every value. But that would preclude directly indexing a vector individually.

Answer (score 1):

A boolean vector length M, equates to an M bit binary number in the range 0..2^M-1. That reduces the problem to generating unique pseudo-random numbers in the given range.

There are a number of possible methods. For guaranteed uniqueness you could use encryption. Just encrypt the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, ... while keeping the key the same.

Comment: "That reduces the problem to generating unique pseudo-random numbers in the given range." Huh?!? It was never stated that original sets are uniformly distributed. If they are, problem is close to trivial.

Comment: Both "pseudo-random" and "unique" are mentioned in the question. Uniform distribution was not mentioned either way, so I ignored it. An encryption will produce unique pseudo-random numbers. A good encryption will not give a uniform distribution, a weak encryption might.

Comment: So what is your "pseudo-random numbers in the given range"  in terms of distribution means? Is the probability the same for each number in he range? That it's uniform.

Comment: Assuming a good encryption is used, AES say, then yes, the numbers will be uniform. Why is that an issue? The question does not specify a non-uniform distribution.

Comment: It might be an issue because being uniform in index (over the set) sampling is not the same as being uniform in the [0...2^M) bit range